Unexpected HTTP Request to Controller Method Causes 403 Forbidden in Dynamically Generated Form
I have a anchor tag in dashboard_view.php that's designed like a button that redirect to the view_cart controller method.
<a class="show_cart" href="<?=base_url('ProductsController/view_cart');?>">Cart (0)</a>

I have a Controller method that loads the page that contains the form.
public function view_cart() {
    $this->load->view('customer/cart_view');
}

Here's the flow:

I fetch the products and put it in the form individually.

cart_view.php
$(document).ready(function() {
    getCartProducts();
    processProductQuantityForm();

    function getCartProducts() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?=base_url('ProductsController/getCartProducts');?>",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
            $.each(response.cart_items, function(index, cart) {
                let cartItem = `<form action="" class="product" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="cart_id" value="${cart.cart_id}">
                                    <input type="text" class="csrf" value="123">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="<?=base_url('${cart.image_url}');?>" alt="">
                                            <h3>${cart.name}</h3>
                                            <span>₱${cart.price}</span>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Quantity</label>
                                                    <input type="text" min-value="1" id="quantity" data-cart_id="${cart.cart_id}" value="${cart.quantity}" name="quantity">
                                                    <!--NOTE: This is the button that triggers the submit-->
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><button type="button" class="increase_quantity" data-quantity-ctrl="1"></button></li>
                                                        <li><button type="button" class="decrease_quantity" data-quantity-ctrl="0"></button></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Total Amount</label>
                                                    <span class="total_amount" data-price="${cart.price}" id="total_amount">₱${cart.total_amount}</span>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <button type="button" class="remove_item"></button>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                                <div>
                                                    <p>Are you sure you want to remove this item?</p>
                                                    <button type="button" class="cancel_remove">Cancel</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button>
                                                </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </form>`;
                        $('.cart_items_form').append(cartItem);
                    });
                    updateProductQuantity();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('AJAX Error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
});


User submits a form to update the quantity, triggering an AJAX call that updates product quantity in the cart.

function updateProductQuantity() {
    $('.product').on('click', '.increase_quantity, .decrease_quantity', function() {
        let quantityInput = $(this).closest('form').find('#quantity');
        let quantity = quantityInput.attr('value');
        let newValue;

        if ($(this).hasClass('increase_quantity')) {
            quantityInput.attr('value', function(index, oldValue){
            newValue = parseInt(oldValue, 10) + 1;
                return newValue;
            });
        } else if (quantity > 1) {
            quantityInput.attr('value', function(index, oldValue) {
                newValue = parseInt(oldValue, 10) - 1;
                return newValue;
            });
        }
        /*Submit the form when these buttons are clicked, containing the new quantity, csrf token and cart id*/
        $(this).closest('.product').submit();
        updateTotal(quantityInput);
    });


Upon successful AJAX response, I update the CSRF token within the submitted form.

function processProductQuantityForm() {
    $('.cart_items_form').on('submit', '.product', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?=base_url('ProductsController/processProductQuantityForm');?>",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $(".csrf").val(response.result.newCsrfToken);
                $("input[name='<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>']").val(response.result.newCsrfToken);
                    },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('AJAX error:', textStatus, errorThrown);

            }
        });
    })
}

The problem is:
Immediately after, an unintended HTTP POST request to http://localhost/thrifted-threads/ProductsController/view_cart is automatically triggered, resulting in a 403 Forbidden error. I cannot determine why this request is happening. But it's running successfully in frontend and it's successfully updating the quantity in the database.


FormData() doesn’t output json by default, have you checked what’s getting sent?

@IanMcL yes, I checked the payload of processProductQuantityForm and it did sucessfully sent the quantity, cart_id & csrf token. It's all working fine, it updated the quantity in the database and in the frontend, It's just when I checked the network tab, after I submit the form,  there's  a HTTP POST request to http://localhost/thrifted-threads/ProductsController/view_cart and I can't figure out why
